# JSON parsing without an identifier

Tags: python, json

Let's say I do a Get request to an API and it's giving me this output in JSON.

```
[
  {
    symbol: "Banana",
    price_usd: 448.66,
    randomthing:123
  },

  {
    symbol: "Apple",
    price_usd: 7.28,
    randomthing:233
  }
]
```

How should I find out the price of `Apple`?

Comment: is the output being stored in a .json file?

Comment: I got u fam `[item for item in __import__('json').loads(__import__('requests').get('http://api.fruitstand.com/fruits').text) if item['symbol'] == 'Apple']['price_usd']`

Comment: I don't know what Json is, but that's not JSON.

Comment: @ap That doesn't work.

Comment: @IchSkill Could you add your relevant code?

Comment: This is just regular Python data; it's not JSON. Please don't use the JSON tag unless you're actually trying to parse or generate JSON, not just doing regular (non-JSON-related) operations on data that *used to be* JSON but isn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's not Python, either. You get `NameError: name 'symbol' is not defined` for that. It's not clear what they actually have.

Comment: You're right -- and it's not valid YAML either.

Answer (score 0):

```
for obj in json_list:
   if obj.get('symbol') == "Apple":
       ...
```